# Activatingtags for dispatcher

Tags: adobe, aem

I have imported a package with /etc/tags data in author instance then I clicked on replicate tags. The tags got replicated to publish instance but not on dispatcher.

Is it a caching issue? How to do I get the same tag values on dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have wrong understanding of dispatcher - it's used only for caching static content (like html, js, css) and load balancing. 
On the other hand - tags are entities in repository, and they are not served to end users by AEM, so they can not be cached.